# css rule applied on the wrong direction on edge

Tags: css

I have the following css:

```
.etichetta{
    /*imposto nascoste le etichette del menu*/
    display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /*mostro le etichette quando lo schermo è abbastanza grande*/
    .etichetta{
        display: contents;
    }

}
```

It will hide all the span with class `etichetta`. Then, if the screen size fits the media query it will be displayed.

It works flawlessy in all the browsers but not in Edge. In that case if I inspect the page and then manually suppress the `display: none;` the span are displayed correctly. Why on Edge it is not overwriting the first rule with the second?

On Edge:

[image]

On Firefox:

[image]

Comment: display: contents is not supported in IE. https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE not support this. You can use `display:inline-block`

Comment: yes, or inline or block. Depending on the final result I want to achieve. Thanks, it the same feedback as the comment previously received